# PHP how to use a variable in match

Tags: php, regex

I am using the blow code to see if my password contains special char which works fine. but I would like to be able to use a variable like `$mySpecialChar` instead of the `"[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]"` string, I'm not sure if I can do that. Reason for that is because I want to be able to pull string from a datatable.
I've tried `preg_match_all("/".$mySpecialChar."/")`, but no luck.

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all("/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/", $pwd, $matches) > 0) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) { $specialcase += strlen($match); }
}
```

Comment: Just assign the whole string to the variable? $mySpecialChar = "/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/";

Comment: There is no reason it wouldn't work. $mySpecialChar = "[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]"; and preg_match_all('/'.$mySpecialChar.'/', $pwd, $matches). This will work.

Comment: Notice Undefined variable: `$specialcase`

Comment: You can use `preg_quote` or `/\Q;\E/` replacing `;` with the symbol you need to use. You shouldn't test against specific characters for passwords though. Instead check against the existing of a character that matches `[^\p{L}\p{N}]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to escape any variables you put in a regular expression

```
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($mySpecialChar, '/').'/', $pwd, $matches);
```

[preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

> string preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )
>
> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.
>   The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -
>
> Note that / is not a special regular expression character.

You have 5 or more special characters in there.

Of note is that last line in the quote above `Note that / is not a special regular expression character.`  While not entirely necessary in your case (I don't see / in your variable string), If you put the second argument as the delimiter it will escape that too. If you pay close attention to what I put above, you will see that is exactly what I did, `preg_quote($mySpecialChar, '/')`

If you don't quote these, well it's anyone guess what it will do. you could get an error, you could get an empty capture group `()` you could match anything with the `.` etc. etc.  AS you have it,

`[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]`

This is a character set, so it will escape most of the stuff inside it, that's if that's intentional.  If you had `[^\'£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]` you would have a not (or negative) character set.

Seeing as you are using `preg_match_all`, and not `preg_match`, I can probably assume you don't want the character set. Otherwise why use `preg_match_all`

It should simply be, if you want to match everything in `$mySpecialChar`:

```
 preg_match('/['.preg_quote($mySpecialChar, '/').']+', $pwd, $matches);
```

If you are just trying to match the stuff between the `[....]`, I would still escape it as it doesn't matter, but if you put it in a database and have  it start with `^` instead it will make a difference, or if you get the `-` between certain characters `0-9` for example it may make a difference.   Escaping never hurts, just remove the `[]` when you save it and replace them as I have above.

The `[ .... ]+` means 1 or more, the `[ ... ]*` means none or more. the `[...]+
?` means one or more non-gready  etc.  Then you should be able to use just `[...]+` with preg_match which will give you a cleaner match then using `[...]` match one, with preg_match_all.

Most of the time `\W` (uppercase) will also match most symbols, basically that means `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` or not `a-Z`, `0-9` and `_`

Comment: He's matching a character set; the only special characters within a character set are `]`, `^`, `\ ` and `-`. OP doesn't have `]`, `^` is only special at start, and `-` is specifically not special at the end where OP has it; the only special character they have unquoted is `\ `. Not sure where you found "5 or more special characters".

Comment: @Amadan - your assuming the character set is intentional, which I am not. Otherwise why use preg_match_all.  It's certainly not clear in the question,  `instead of the "[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]" string`  Not to mention, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Ok how would i list all char i want a match against ? i need to return how often any char in the string is matched against any of the char in the match criteria.

Comment: `often any char` does that mean you want to count how often each char is matched, or how many in the set is matched?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just look for characters that AREN'T the basic ones:

```
preg_match_all('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/', $pwd, $matches)
```

Much shorter and just as effective.

You can easily put this in a string if you like:

```
$specialChars = '[^0-9A-Za-z]';
preg_match_all("/{$specialChars}/", $pwd, $matches);
```

Running this on the provided password will return an array in `$matches` which contains all of the special characters from the string. All you need to do in order to evaluate password complexity is look at the length of `$pwd` and how many entries are in `$matches`, as this tells you the number of special characters.

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear why i can not use the last suggestion in my solution. This match for special char is used to evaluate the strength of a provided password by a user. For example based on a users profile his password might be required to have 1 or 2 special char in his password. So i run the match before i allow him to save it, if count is less the required per profile i reject it. So i hope that makes it a bit more clear why i am doing this.